# How can I escape the switch and while(1) loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, switch-statement, escaping

Thanks for stopping by to see this. This was made from Visual c++.

I wanted to make a random problem with a random number and arithmetic operations.

It's supposed to give me a new problem until I get the right answer and when I get the right answer, It's supposed to be stopped and closed. But, even if I get the right answer, it doesn't let me escape the loop but keeps giving me a new problem. Please check out the following code I made.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int ans;
    srand(time(0));
    printf("Making a random problem. \n");

    int x = rand() % 100;
    int y = rand() % 100;
    int op = rand() % 4;

    while (1) {

        switch (op)
        {
        case 0:
            printf("%d + %d = ", x, y);
            scanf("%d", &ans);
            if (x + y == ans)
            {
                printf("correct.\n");
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("wrong.\n");
        case 1:
            printf("%d - %d = ", x, y);
            scanf("%d", &ans);
            if (x - y == ans)
            {
                printf("correct.\n");
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("wrong.\n");
        case 2:
            printf("%d * %d = ", x, y);
            scanf("%d", &ans);
            if (x * y == ans)
            {
                printf("correct.\n");
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("wrong.\n");
        case 3:
            printf("%d / %d = ", x, y);
            scanf("%d", &ans);
            if (x / y == ans)
            {
                printf("correct.\n");
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("wrong.\n");
        }
        break; //*1
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Can you please tell me how to escape the loop when I get the right answer?
I thought the *1 break around the bottom would let me escape but It didn't work. I'll appreciate it in advance.

Comment: You can call `continue;`

Comment: The `break` after/outside of  `switch` will leave your `while` loop in any case. If you want to prevent this then end all cases (incl. maybe a `default:`) with `continue` to skip this (except the `case 1`, of course).

Comment: I see this Kind of problem as a message from the Giver Of Data that you're packing too much into one function. If you move the loop and the switch into another function, you can `return` when you want out of the loop.

Comment: A more maintenance friendly variation would be to use a flag (e.g. a `bool` variable) which is initially set to `false`, checked in the `while` condition and set to `true` only if you want to leave the loop.

Comment: Note: Whatever learning materials you are using seem to be teaching you C, not C++. There are some pretty big difference between the two languages.

Comment: How about putting the loop inside of a function and using return?

Comment: thanks for all of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the *1 break around the bottom would let me escape but It didn't work. I'll appreciate it in advance.

**It will break the loop.** But it will break the loop for both incorrect and correct answers (which isn't what you want).

I think you get confused by another bug which is in the switch-case statement. For each case, you need to put the break in the end of the case. If you don't, the execution continues with the next case. So:

```
    case 0:
        printf("%d + %d = ", x, y);
        scanf("%d", &ans);
        if (x + y == ans)
        {
            printf("correct.\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("wrong.\n");
```

should be

```
    case 0:
        printf("%d + %d = ", x, y);
        scanf("%d", &ans);
        if (x + y == ans)
        {
            printf("correct.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("wrong.\n");
        }
        break;
```

or a bit more compact:

```
    case 0:
        printf("%d + %d = ", x, y);
        scanf("%d", &ans);
        printf("%s.\n", (x + y == ans) ? "correct" : "wrong");
        break;
```

So back to the orginal problem:

> How to break the while-loop **only when the answer is correct**.

There are many ways to solve this. A classic solution is to use a flag, i.e. instead of `while(1)` do something like `bool answer_wrong = true; while(answer_wrong) { .. };` and then change `answer_wrong` when you get a correct answer.

Here is another solution for your specific problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int ans;
    srand(time(0));
    printf("Making a random problem. \n");

    int x = rand() % 100;
    int y = rand() % 100;
    int op = rand() % 4;

    char op_char;        
    int correct_answer;

    // Calculate the correct answer
    switch (op)
    {
        case 0:
            correct_answer = x + y;
            op_char = '+';
            break;
        case 1:
            correct_answer = x - y;
            op_char = '-';
            break;
        case 2:
            correct_answer = x * y;
            op_char = '*';
            break;
        case 3:
            correct_answer = x / y;
            op_char = '/';
            break;
    }

    // Keep looping till you get the correct answer
    while (1) {
        printf("%d %c %d = ", x, op_char, y);
        scanf("%d", &ans);
        if (ans == correct_answer)
        {
            printf("correct.\n");

            // Answer correct so break the while loop
            break;
        }

        printf("wrong.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the user input is taken outside the `switch` statement and therefore you can break out of the `while` immediately when the answer is correct.

BTW:

Never do

```
scanf("%d", &ans);
```

always check the return value like:

```
if (scanf("%d", &ans) != 1)
{
    // ups - bad input - add error handling
}
```